# create-react-app and d3 - Why is d3 undefined?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm using create-react-app to get my app started, and I want to use d3 in my components.  I'm using node 6.3.1.  I have run

> npm install d3 --save

and can see d3 in my package.json. So why don't I have d3?  Here's my component class; it reports that d3 is undefined.

```
import React from 'react'
import d3 from 'd3'

var Grid = React.createClass({
  render: () => {
    console.log('d3', d3) // reports "d3 undefined"
    return (<div/>)
  }
})

export default Grid
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

d3 is not a top level export, but you can import everything and save it to d3 namespace

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
```

Or just import the functions you intend on using.